# Refitting the ANOVA model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, interaction, two-way

I have performed a Two way ANOVA,  for one response and two categorical variables. I had found that

1. EDA with a plot of means shows that there might be an interaction between my categorical varibles
2. However, the null hypothesis of no interaction between the two variables is supported in the ANOVA table

Should I now refit the model, now this time using ANOVA with no interaction. Does it depend on the context of the data? If so, what might I be looking to say to justify refitting the model.